# How can I cast &&T to *const *const T?

Tags: rust

```
 let val = &&10;
 let ptr_ptr = val as *const *const i32; // casting `&&i32` as `*const *const i32` is invalid
```

I've thought that **&&10** reserves 3 elements on a stack: 4 byte for value and 8 + 8 bytes for two pointers on x64. So, why there is a compiler error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example, till the error, is a decomposition of your attempt.

Your attempt to convert references to pointers seems correct because [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#pointers-and-references-layout) of the reference states

> Pointers and references have the same layout

The `as` conversion you wrote implies **two** conversions at once.
[This section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions) of the reference gives a table of the conversions `as` can perform.
We find `&T` to `*const T` (interpreting the footnotes of the table), but not `&&T` to `*const *const T` because `&T` is not `*const T` (we need another conversion for that).

You can perform them as in the next expression, or decompose in many stages.

```rust
fn main() {
    let val = 10;
    let ref_val = &val;
    let ref_ref_val = &ref_val;
    // let ptr_ptr_val = ref_ref_val as *const *const i32; // ERROR
    //
    let ptr_ptr_val = ref_ref_val as *const &i32 as *const *const i32;
    println!("{} {}", **ref_ref_val, unsafe { **ptr_ptr_val });
    //
    let ptr_ptr_val = &&10 as *const &i32 as *const *const i32;
    println!("{}", unsafe { **ptr_ptr_val });
    //
    let ptr_ptr_val: *const *const i32 = &(&10 as *const i32);
    println!("{}", unsafe { **ptr_ptr_val });
    //
    let ptr_val = ref_val as *const i32;
    let ref_ptr_val = &ptr_val;
    let ptr_ptr_val = ref_ptr_val as *const *const i32;
    println!("{} {}", **ref_ref_val, unsafe { **ptr_ptr_val });
}
/*
10 10
10
10
10 10
*/
```

Comment: yes, but for what reason **&&10 as *const *const i32** is forbidden by the compiler?

Comment: @user3070377 because two conversions are needed, but `as` only performs one. Maybe you have a C background, and actually C allows almost any conversions at once; I understand your remark. I added the `&&10` case.

Comment: Is dereferencing a `*const *const T` that was cast from a `*const &T` defined behavior? I'm not sure if `*const T` and `&T` are guaranteed to have the same layout.
The documentation for `*const T` doesn't explicitly state that, and since there can be layout optimizations, such as `&Option<T>` being the same size as a pointer, I'm not sure if it is safe.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues if each invocation of `as` conforms to a valid situation in the table of the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions), why wouldn't it be safe? `as` is not as dangerous as a classic C cast, and is rejected when the compiler knows the layouts don't match. The only exception I see is reaching `usize`, then casting back to a pointer towards a totally unrelated type.

Comment: @prog-fh `*const T as *const U` can be done in safe code for any T and U, but dereferencing the result is UB if T and U aren't "compatible"

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues thanks for all of your remarks (this encourages to investigate deeper). I added a link to [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#pointers-and-references-layout) to make clear that we are not in the situation you describe. I totally agree with you, your example with `*const T as *const U` is equivalent to what I suggested with `usize`. Moreover, the `*T` to `*V` entry in the table of the reference warns about the compatibility of the types. But the question and the answer are about the same type `T` accessed via a reference or a pointer.